# debugging a sbt project with intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I'm just getting started with scala and sbt.  I've downloaded the sbt project https://github.com/spray/spray-template and I'm trying to debug run it.  It makes/builds fine and I can get the unit tests to run with a specs2 configuration.

What run configuration should I use to run the web server and debug it?  When I click on add new configuration I see Scala console and scala script as choices but doesn't look like either one is the equivalent of running re-start from the sbt console.  How should I configure the debug run configuration so that I can get one click running of the project with the debugger attached?

Comment: how about a command for starting the main app from console, what command would I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used spray-template but it looks like you can run the com.example.Boot class under the debugger from within IntelliJ. You should be able to right-click the class and run/debug it.